# Extension Method to assign value to a field in every item?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, iqueryable

I could have sworn that there was an extension method already built for the Queryable class that I just can't find, but maybe I'm thinking of something different.

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
IQueryable<Entity> en = from e in IDB.Entities select e;
en.ForEach(foo => foo.Status = "Complete");
```

en.Foreach() would essential perform:

```
foreach(Entity foo in en){
   foo.Status = "Complete";
}
```

Is this already written?  If not, is it possible to write said Extension Method, preferably allowing for any LINQ Table and any Field on that table.  Where is a good place to start?

Comment: What is Entity class, a class defined by you. If that's the case, then you got to write the status property, right?

Comment: @gisresearch, the fact he made Entity is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a foreach on a List<>. Roughly something along these lines:

```
IQueryable<Entity> en = from e in IDB.Entities select e;
en.ToList().ForEach(foo => foo.status = "Complete");
```

Comment: There it is!  I had a suspicion that this functionality what already here, I just wasn't looking in the right place.  Casting it to a List<> is perfectly acceptable, and this is what I needed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing in the base class library. Many, *many* developers have this in their own common library, however, and we have it in [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) too.

It sort of goes against the spirit of LINQ, in that it's all about side-effects - but it's really useful,  so I think pragmatism trumps dogma here.

One thing to note - there's really no point in using a query expression in your example. (It's not *entirely* redundant, but if you're not exposing the value it doesn't matter.) The select isn't doing anything useful here. You can just do:

```
IDB.Entities.ForEach(foo => foo.status = "Complete");
```

Even if you want to do a single "where" or "select" I'd normally use dot notation:

```
IDB.Entities.Where(foo => foo.Name == "fred")
            .ForEach(foo => foo.status = "Complete");
```

Only use query expressions where they actually make the code simpler :)

Comment: Very articulate answer, and I appreciate the response.  The actual query expression is much more complicate; I just reduced it for simplicity of the question.  Also, thank you for the link to MORELinq.  There are a lot of helpful things I've found over there.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest a different name to avoid a conflict on Lists. Perhaps OnEach<T>(..)?

Comment: @Samuel, I wouldn't. Both functions do the same thing, so you really don't mind being unable to easily call this version on a List. This way, you can simply use ForEach on any IEnumerable`1 - a List or not.

Comment: This answer was really helpful.  The other part of my problem was knowing the keyword to build my own Extension method to perform an action of every item in a sequence.  The "Action" delegate got me pointed on the right road to simplifying the fix for all kinds of problems. Thanks.